# Angular 9 push notifications for android

Tags: angular, firebase, cordova, push-notification, push

I created **Angular 9** app with Firebase push notifications for Web. Then i create a native app with Cordova. How to implement push notifications for android?

Comment: Hi! You need to provide us some information about your tentative. Here some guidelines to be able to post a good answer: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Google Firebase Cloud Messaging Cordova Push Plugin](https://github.com/andrehtissot/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated). This is the updated plugin. You can find Demo source code [here](https://github.com/andrehtissot/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated-ionic-v3-example). Even if the demo code is of ionic v3. It also applies for ionic v4 with little changes.

Comment: Hi thanks for answer, I have angular 9 project without ionic, I use cordova only to convert web app to mobile.